# Where can I get previous versions of MIMIC-III?

Tags: mimic-iii

The current version of MIMIC-III is 1.3, and can be obtain [here](https://physionet.org/works/MIMICIIIClinicalDatabase/files/). Where can I get [previous versions of MIMIC-III](https://mimic.physionet.org/about/releasenotes/)? Namely, versions 1.1 and 1.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the most up-to-date version is made available to the research community via PhysioNet, but past versions are archived and may be shared upon request. Contact information is available on the MIMIC website (http://mimic.physionet.org/help/).